# File won't save with Imagick

Tags: php, image-uploading, imagick

I have not changed anything on my website, but recently when users use the form for uploading an image, the file won't save with Imagick. There is no error. Here is a snippet:

```
$file = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];

$im = new Imagick($file);

$im->setImageBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel("white"));
$im->setFormat ("jpg");
$im->cropThumbnailImage(100,100); 
$im->writeImages('/path/to/thumb0000.jpg',false);
```

Edit: Thanks to T K, I found the following message in the error-log:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - libMagickWand.so.2: can not open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0.
```

Solved: I have installed the package php-pecl-imagick and everything works again!

Comment: Did you take a look at the apache error log?

Comment: Thank you, I've worked out how I can get to the error_log. There is indeed a message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - libMagickWand.so.2: can not open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0. However, I see the file in this location in my filemanager. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Make sure the file it complained about is actually there and that the php account (usually the web server account) has access to it. If both are true, make sure it's dependencies are all there and accessible.

Comment: I solved the problem! I have installed the package php-pecl-imagick and everything works again! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Your write destination is absolute and unlikely writable by the www user.

```
 $im->writeImages('/path/to/thumb0000.jpg',false);
```

Check your actual path and make sure it exists, and you can write there

Comment: Thnks, but te problem is not de path. The one that I use is right, because I had never problems with it. I have impoved my question, thnks to T K.